# Y-axis value (class probability) more than 1 in a Random Forest PDP

Tags: classification, random-forest, partial-plot

Sometimes I am getting such PDPs from a Random Forest classification (two-class) model. Why Y-axis probability is more than 1 here? What might have caused it?

[image: PDP from Random Forest Classification Model]

Comment: Hard to say without details. What is your model, which software do you use, what data do you have...?

Comment: Thanks. I used R randomForest library for the model and partialPlot method to generate these partial dependence plots. As shown in these PDPs, I was trying to predict the wildfire occurrence probability using a range of predictor variables. Three predictor's partial dependence with fire probability shown here. But the probability on the Y-axis is sometimes more than 1, that's where I am curious why this is happening.

Comment: Note that, one predictor in the model (not shown here in the graph) is a factor variable with 10 levels. When I run model without this variable, Y-axis probability range stays between  -1 and 1. But when I include that in the model then Y-axis range goes beyond 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/partialPlot#l_details), the PDPs in randomForest for classification problems display y-values in logits.  (Though why then title the axis as "probability"?)

Comment: That's right! Thanks.